# how to change domain and range of d3 graph dynamically?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want each curve of d3 start from top according to its domain and range.

I used starting point[x,y]= [1,8.5] or any points for curve but i do not want  top space between 8.5 to 10.It should be started from 8.5  or any value of Y coordinate.I know it is working according to range[0,10].

**Each curve should be working for**

1. Y coordinate of each curve or path  will be increased based on words.
2. x coordinate of each curve or path  will be increased based on length of words.

does not want to change curve while changing domain [1,8.5] ?

**Code**

```
var path0  = [{x: 1.0, y: 8.5},{x: 2.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 1, y: 1.5}];
var path1 = [{x: 3, y: 8.5},{x: 4.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 3, y: 1.5}];
var path2 = [{x: 5, y: 8.5},{x: 6.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 5, y: 1.5}];
var path3 = [{x: 7, y: 8.5},{x: 8.0, y: 5.0}, {x: 7, y: 1.5}]; 
var path4  = [{x: 1.78, y: 5.0},{x: 1.8, y: 5.0}];
console.log(path0);

var w = 1200,
  h = 850,
  p = 40,

  x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([p, w - p]),
  y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([h - p, p]);



var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("cardinal")
        .x(function(d) { console.log(d);return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { console.log(d); return y(d.y); });



var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .append("svg:g"); 

var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
          .data(x.ticks(10))
          .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "rule"); 

rules.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", x)
    .attr("x2", x)
    .attr("y1", p)
    .attr("y2", h - p - 1);

rules.append("svg:line")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d ? null : "axis"; })
    .attr("y1", y)
    .attr("y2", y)
    .attr("x1", p)
    .attr("x2", w - p + 1);

rules.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", h - p + 3)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(x.tickFormat(10));

rules.append("svg:text")
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("x", p - 3)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(y.tickFormat(10)); 

 vis.selectAll("path.path0")
  .data([0])
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path0); }) 
  .style("stroke","green");
  vis.append("text")
.attr("x", (w / 2))             
.attr("y", (h / 2))
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
.style("font-size", "16px") 
.text("test2");        

vis.append("text")
    .attr("y", 425)
    .attr("x",241.6)
    .attr("dy", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("test1"); 


    vis.append("text")
    .attr("y",4)
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("dx", 15)
    .attr("dy",15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("test"); 




vis.selectAll("path.path1")
  .data([0])
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {  console.log(d);return line.tension(d)(path1); })
  .style("stroke","green");
```

Here you can see working example.
[jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/s2yn3b4p/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope it would be useful for you http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/. Using that approach you may add a `domain` method and use it when necessary to update the chart.

Comment: Here you may find some examples https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/master/src/models

Comment: I do not want to change the curve while changing domain and range.In this If I change domain [0,6] It changes the chart also.Is there any way to not changing path or curve when changing the domain ? may be i am missing something in this.